# osg::GraphicsContext::WindowingSystemInterface returns null

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openscenegraph

In my OpenSceneGraph program, I have the following code:

```
osg::GraphicsContext::WindowingSystemInterface* wsi = osg::GraphicsContext::getWindowingSystemInterface();

    if (!wsi) {
        osg::notify(osg::NOTICE) << "Error, no WindowingSystemInterface available, cannot create windows." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Unfortunately the method getWindowingSystemInterface() returns a null value, so the program cannot continue. What can be the reason that it returns null and how can I change my program (or build settings?) to let it return a non-null value? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are querying the interface before it has been created, so it returns a null.  If you are running with a console window, try setting OSG_NOTIFY_LEVEL environment variable to either INFO or DEBUG, and it will tell you exactly if/when it sets the windowing interface.

See the "set" method (from 3.1.3 dev build anyways), which performs a print if your notify level is INFO or higher:

```
void GraphicsContext::setWindowingSystemInterface(WindowingSystemInterface* callback)
{
    ref_ptr<GraphicsContext::WindowingSystemInterface> &wsref = windowingSystemInterfaceRef();
    wsref = callback;
    OSG_INFO<<"GraphicsContext::setWindowingSystemInterface() "<<wsref.get()<<"\t"<<&wsref<<std::endl;
}
```

http://www.openscenegraph.com/index.php/documentation/debugging-tips